# Where to download the pyflix library?

Tags: python, netflix

I want to download the 'pyflix' library that was previously hosted at http://svn.pyflix.python-hosting.com/trunk/.

That site now gives a 404 error. I found however a cached copy of the code via [Google code search](http://www.google.com/codesearch#85ZDGOWsPEk/docs/README.txt).

Is there an easy way of checking out/downloading this cached code from Google code search?

Comment: Just googling "pyflix" gives http://code.google.com/p/pyflix/, click the source tab for how to download via svn ... am I missing something?

Comment: That is another library with the same name. The one on code.google.com is a module for accessing the [Netflix APIs](http://developer.netflix.com/). The one on python-hosting.com/Google code search is a package for analysing the data of the [Netflix Prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/).

Comment: ah gotcha .... try [this zip](http://web.archive.org/web/20090408033407/http://pyflix.python-hosting.com/changeset/17/tags/pyflix-0.1%3Fold_path%3D%252F%26format%3Dzip) c/o The Wayback Machine

Comment: Thanks! That is indeed the code I was looking for. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [waybackmachine](http://wayback.archive.org/web/) is often useful for digging into the past. The pyflix trac site for 2009 can be found at:

http://web.archive.org/web/20090408033407/http://pyflix.python-hosting.com/